# Pushforward of vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

There is something I am confused about. I am reading Loring An introduction to differential geometry. I am confused why if $F(p) = F(q) = z$, they then have the same push-forward of the vector field. Is it because we are dealing with the same target space. From first inspection:

For $F : N \rightarrow M \in C^{\infty}(M, N)$ map of manifolds we have:

$$F_{*}(X_p)f = X_p(f \circ F)$$
$$F_{*}(X_q)f = X_q(f \circ F)$$

Why are they the same ? I see the picture that Loring posted in his book and it makes sense to me. Though I don't see the rigor involved.

Comment: Did you mean to write $F(p)=F(q)=q$? I assume that $q$ is in $N$ and $F(q)$ is in $M$

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: What is it exactly that is supposed to be the "same"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are not necessarily the same and that's exactly the problem. If you have a smooth map $F \in C^\infty(M, N)$ that is not injective, say $F(p) = F(q) = z$, there might not be a vector fields $Y$ on $N$ that is $F$-related to a vector fields $X$ on $M$, *i.e.*
$$F_{*s}(X_s) = Y_{F(s)}, \quad \forall s \in M.$$
Indeed $Y_{F(p)} = Y_{F(q)} = Y_z$ is not well-defined since $F_{*p}(X_p)$ and $F_{*q}(X_q)$ may not be the same tangent vector.