# Is the differential of a smooth function between two manifolds always a Lie Algebra homomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, differential

I have a quite basic question on the differential of a function and the Lie bracket. Given a smooth map
\begin{equation}
f:M\rightarrow{N}
\end{equation}
between to manifolds. The vector fields on M are closed under the Lie bracket so they form a Lie Algebra. In books I've often seen that the differential $df$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism, i.e.
\begin{equation}
df([X,Y])=[df(X),df(Y)]
\end{equation}
for $X,Y$ vector fields in a region of M. Could someone explain if and why this equation always holds?  I've tried to use the definition of the differential with curves but unfortunately I got stuck.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you've written makes no sense. You need the Lie bracket of vector fields, not of tangent vectors at a point.

Comment: Sorry, I mean vector fields in a region of x.

Comment: Look at the right-hand side of your displayed equation.

Comment: Push forward of a vector field might not be a vector field: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3970530/pushforward-of-vector-field/3970602) for example.

Comment: There is a way to write a correct formula that looks like this, but it’s more complicated. See https://deaneyang.github.io//blog/blog/math/differential-geometry/riemannian-geometry/2021/04/01/PullbackConnection.html